# Is there a substantial feature, performance or compatibility difference between Underscore.js's _.map() and JavaScript's native .map()?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there any reason to use [_.map()](http://underscorejs.org/#map) when JavaScript [already implements .map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: it was added before browsers had it. also it works with the underscore chaining mechanisms

Comment: @DanielA.White does that mean that it will be compatible with older browsers?

Comment: @DanielA.White the native functional methods chain just as well (if not better). It's really just because underscore/lodash got there first.

Comment: @DanielA.White your comments would make a great Answer.

Comment: @meetalexjohnson no need for rep points. this is an off topic question.

Comment: @DanielA.White could you be more specific? Whether there is a feature/performance/compatibility difference between the two implementations is relevant to my programming work and is not primarily opinion based.

Comment: @DanielA.White Title changed to reflect that the question was not intended to illicit opinion

Comment: Factual answer shows that this is not primarily opinion based. Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Key word, that is also wrong: "already."

Underscore's is older. It has not been removed (and shouldn't be, because that would break legacy code).

Comment: A constructive, though not terribly polite, recommendation for editing the title.

Comment: I am not sure underscore is older than the specs. Isn't it just ie 8 was not quite following the specs at that time (which ie 9 solved a moment later)? Firefox was much more compatible back then.